# making a mashup of two songs with different BPM

Tags: editing, recommendations, tricks

in this mashup I tried to combine two songs, one that is BPM 99 and one that is BPM 104, I would like to know, was this effect moderated by the slicing and placements that I made?

Maybe someone could give a more critical listen than myself and let me know what I might improve.

I'm using Bitwig.

Are there known techniques to apply to such situations

https://soundcloud.com/laviusalens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slice up one of the songs (Let's call that song 1 for now, and let's call the song you "Mix" into song 2). Set up a new project for your mashup. Or use the one in which you made the mashup. Then I recommend you set the BPM of the project to the BPM of song 2.

Now you can bring song 1 and 2 into your project. At this point you have to decide if you want to keep the BPM of song 1 as it is, or bring it to the BPM of song 2.

You can slice up song 1 into any musical length you want, like 1/4 (the most used one). Of course you take a slice from the point you want to start bringing in song 2. Now just put a lot of those slices one behind another and try out some nice mixing tricks like fading in song 2 while fading out song 1.

It might take some tries to get nice sounding slice lengths.

Comment: This is the most general way to mashup but it's an art to try something new and it's actually that art that make you stand out as a DJ

Comment: 1/4 notes won't match, you'll get a swing effect. You need to slice 1/8ths *at least*, to catch the off-beats. And bear in mind the sliced song 's tempo can only go up, if you don't want gaps.

Comment: I personally like a swing effect in a buildup (If that is the part where the transition happends I think it would be ok) also gaps just depends on your timestreatching algoritm. Ableton for example does not create gabs when you use the complex or conplex pro algoritms

Comment: You can't have a swing on one track and not on the other if you're mixing two songs, it'll probably be a very awkwood, non-musical swing too. You didn't mention time stretching, Yes, you could overcome the gaps by stretching the slices. But then why not simply time stretch the whole track?

Comment: Because streatching makes you loose more quality when you increase the amount of data to procces (again speaking from an ableton point of view)

Comment: If you use the same algorithm, I can't see why quality would be dependent on processing load. Ableton used to use the same algorithms as Cubase and other DAWs, I don't know about now though. What I used to do to remove these gaps is to repeat the slice, and reverse it, this works for big drops in tempo too. I got the idea from ReCycle a few years back.

Comment: In the end ot totely depends on s.mattew's style and choises

Comment: Yes, I was simply using my knowledge and experience to improve on your answer to help the OP with his problem. If you don't agree, that's fine with me. [It's how SE works](http://sound.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). We're all here to share and learn after all.

Answer (score 0):

You could slice one of the songs in order to make it fit, yeah. By what I hear, you got rid of pauses and silences. That's one way to do it. Other way is to change pitch slightly of both files, so they are in closer relation tempo-wise to each other. Finally, you can mix both techniques. Basically, you shoudln't care about estabilished practices at this point and just experiment. If something works for you, it works period.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to first match the BPMs. When this is done the creativity can flow unimpaired. The best way is to increase the lowest tempo to match the highest(compress the lowest track's length). Another way is to adjust both songs to "meet in the middle". Some software's better than others for time stretching. I use Serato software when I play live, and the pitch lock sounds great.

You can find the BPM of a song by using software, or by doing some simple maths, if you know how many bars are in the track, and you know the time scale from first to last beat, then you can find the BPM.

If you still want to match one track to the other by splitting it up, split it into eights notes at least, and to save hastle, don't decrease the tempo on the split track(this will create gaps). Maybe Bitwig has a way of automating this splitting process. Remember to be precice with cutting and placement.

In the past, I would create mash-ups on my decks with just the two vinyls, using the pitch adjustment to match them. No pitch-lock, editing on-the-fly and people loved them. There is no 'wrong' way to do these things, all that matters is if you like the outcome.